# Import common task properties to build.gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

We have several libraries that have common task configurations, I'd like to break these out into a Gradle plugin, rather than have them duplicated into every repo. Is there a way to do this? I can't find anything in the docs.

Current state:
(this exists in all repos)

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'OS': "${System.getProperty('os.name')}"
                // many more things here

        )
    }
}
```

Desired state:

- central repo with plugin defined
- each repo just imports the plugin to get the `jar` task

```
plugins {
    id 'my-custom-plugin'
}
```

Would also be okay with doing:

```
apply from: 'other.gradle'
```

but the `other.gradle` would need to live in a central repository.

Comment: There's a video here which I believe shows what you're after https://youtu.be/XnVZdMROVG8

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you! If you want to make this an answer I'll mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: Jendrick really knows his stuff, and all his videos are excellent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is a convention plugin, the best resource showing how to set one up is in this video https://youtu.be/XnVZdMROVG8

There's also a couple of examples in the documentation, IE:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html
https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_publishing_convention_plugins.html

But the video (all of them in that channel are worth watching) is the best imho